# my canvas does not show the location of the wall until you input initial velocity and launch angle

Tags: python, python-3.x, vpython

I am building a simplified version of the popular game angry birds, a bird is launched to a wall, a series of calculations are taken to decide if the bird can hit the wall and topple it if possible.But my canvas does not show the location of the wall until you input initial velocity and launch angle. Can anyone help me with this? Really appreciated for that!
Here is my code about scene

```
scene = canvas(width=640, height=480, center=vector(8,0,0),range=8)#scene
ground = curve(pos=[(0,0,0),(16,0,0)],color=color.green)#set up ground
target = box (pos= vector(targetx,1.0,0), length=0.5, width=0.5, 
height=2.0)#set up target wall
bird = sphere(pos = vector(0,0,0), radius = 0.05, make_trail=True )#set up bird
#mylabel = canvas.create_text((0, 20), text="Label text")
```

Answer (score 0):

The curve pos must be a list of vectors, like this:

curve(pos=[vector(0,0,0),vector(16,0,0)],color=color.green)

And you need to define targetx.